# PHP mysqli multiple databases on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code is like this...

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));
}

//use $link works fine
mysqli_close($link);


$link2 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (!$link2) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link2));
}
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link2, DB_NAME);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link2));
}

if (!mysqli_query($link2, $sql)) {
    die('Error ' . mysqli_error($link2));
}
```

and I get an error like

> $link.TableNameFromLink2 does not exist

so basically even though I am closing the first link and opening a new one it is still defaulting to the first link when trying to connect to the table I want that exists in the second link... I don't get it.. It's killing me :(

Comment: What does the $sql contains ?

Comment: there is no need to use this line `$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);` as you have already given `DB_NAME` in `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: multiple Database => it means that you want to connect to other DB => do you provide correct DB name to `$link2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `$link2` you are using same `CONSTANT` DB info as you used in `$link`
You have to use another CONSTANT to define another DB details.
like

```
define('DB_USER','user1');
define('DB_PASSWORD','password1');
define('DB_NAME','dbname1');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
// for 2nd db ( if username and password is same then no need to define DB_USER1 and DB_PASSWORD1)

define('DB_USER1','user2');
define('DB_PASSWORD1','password2');
define('DB_NAME1','dbname2');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$link2 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER1, DB_PASSWORD1, DB_NAME1);
```

Comment: ^ I knew I was doing something dumb... thanks I hope this works!

Comment: it worked, I'm a bit new to php but I should have known this from general programming, however it was a mistake so dumb I would have never saw it. thank you.